# Parse database is replacing objects when it should create a new one

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a while without success. I have a button works like this:

- Query the videosTable class in Parse and if the value for videoID (that I get from youtube's API) is not existent, create a new PFObject with rating 0. Otherwise, increase the rating by one.

The result however, is that the first new object I try to create every time I launch the app has no problem, but if I create another new object during the same run/session, the object previously created gets replaced by this new one.

The objectID stays the same, so I'm guessing this has something to do with the query not getting closed (or something similar), resulting in me modifying the previous object, instead of creating a new one.

Can someone shed some light in this?

```
@IBAction func recomBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "VideosInfo")
    query.whereKey("Video_ID", equalTo: videoID)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if objects?.count == 0 {
               print(objects)
               videosTable["Video_ID"] = self.videoID
               videosTable["Rating"] = 1
               videosTable.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    print("Rating Created")
                } else {
                    print(error?.description)
                }}
            } else {
                objects![0].incrementKey("Rating")
                print("Rating Increased")
                videosTable.saveInBackground()
                }} else {
                print(error?.description)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After much reviewing, I found out I was making a very dumb mistake! I declared the PFObject outside of the function! So when I was done with my button, the PFObject remained! (Since I don't really close the view after I go to another video, the PFObject remained as a property of the class until I closed the app).

Thanks anyway for your help!